# respond_with redirect with notice flash message not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, redirect

I am using rails 3.0.7. In the controller I have:

```
  def create
    @subscription = Subscription\
      .new_from_nested_attributes_parameters(params[:subscription])

    if @subscription.save
      flash[:notice] = 'The Subscription was successfully created.'
    end

    respond_with @subscription
  end
```

and in the view:

```
<%="Notice:#{flash[:notice]}"%>
```

Doesn't print anything despite that the object is being properly saved.

Do you have an idea on how should I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I discovered the problem.

flash[:notice]="...." is properly working on the create action, redirecting to the show action.

What I forgot was that my 'show' consists on a redirect to edit.

I fixed this by implementing the show action like this:

```
def show
  redirect_to edit_subscription_path(@subscription),flash
end
```

From Rails 3.1 on, this should be accomplished with:

```
def show
  flash.keep
  redirect_to edit_subscription_path(@subscription)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

In Rails 3.2, the following will work and appears to keep the flash intact:

```
respond_with @subscription, :location => edit_subscription_path(@subscription)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can skip the show page:

Instead of:

```
respond_with @subscription
```

Put:

```
respond_with @subscription, edit_subscription_path(@subscription)
```

Comment: this does not work for redirecting to subscriptions_path (i.e. #index)