# Why am I getting this printed instead of my flash message? #<ActionDispatch::Flash::FlashHash:0x7fd9f99acc90>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have upgraded my application to Rails 3.1 and now this is appearing where there should be the flash[:notice] message:`#<ActionDispatch::Flash::FlashHash:0x7fd9f99acc90>`.

When inspecting the value, I end up concluding that the 'variable' `flash` is a `ActionDispatch::Flash::FlashHash` and contains a `ActionDispatch::Flash::FlashHash` as value for the `notice` key.

Did anyone have the same problem? How can I fix this?

The flash is being set with:

```
flash.notice = "The Subscription was created successfully."
```

or with

```
redirect_to(blablabla_path,
            :notice => 'The Subscription was successfully updated.')
```

and it's being printed with (haml):

```
- if notice
      .notice= notice
```

This is happening to me in every action..

There's more about the code where this problem is occuring here:
[respond_with redirect with notice flash message not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101631/respond-with-redirect-with-notice-flash-message-not-working)

Comment: Weird. Could you show some of your code where you are setting `flash` messages?

Comment: You are probably passing the wrong value in your controller, the flash will accept anything you put into it, an object for example.

Comment: Don't you need to use `flash[:notice]`?

Comment: that was the old syntax. I am getting the same results when I use it.

Comment: I don't see how that's possible if you're accessing an entry explicitly. (Or `flash.notice` I guess.)

Comment: It's Ruby. Almost anything is possible. For the good and for the bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was fixed.

The show redirect has been preceeded by `flash.keep` instead of explicitly passing the flash as argument.